# How to change the image displayed within a Gtk.EventBox?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

I am trying to implement a clickable image with GTK and Vala. From what I read, the best way to do this is with an EventBox. However, one of my requirements is to change the image displayed within the EventBox. I tried to do this as follows, but, even though the first image disappears on click, the second one never shows up. Why is this? What am I missing here?

```
using Gtk;

class Window : Gtk.Window {
    private EventBox evbox = new EventBox ();
    private Image img_a = new Image ();
    private Image img_b = new Image ();

    public Window () {
        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);

        img_a.set_from_file ("a.png");
        img_b.set_from_file ("b.png");

        evbox.button_press_event.connect ( () => { swap_img (); return true; } );
        evbox.add (img_a);

        this.add (evbox);
    }

    public void swap_img () {
        evbox.remove (img_a);
        evbox.add (img_b);
    }


    public static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args);

        var window = new Window ();

        window.show_all ();
        Gtk.main ();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to call `img_b.show()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. So just to make sure that I understand, since I seemingly don't need to call img_a.show(), does window.show_all() call the show() method on all children and subchildren of the window? So, since img_b is not a child of anything initally, it's not shown?

Comment: Correct. This is all explained in the reference documentation.

Comment: You're right, I digged into the documenation and found it, thanks! But then the other question would be, what should keep me from calling the show method one every image as soon as I set it from file. Does this affect memory usage or something else? What does show really do in the background if the image isn't a child of any container yet?